# Pimcore: Cannot use Pimcore\Model\Object after update to Pimcore 4

Tags: pimcore

After updating Pimcore to version 5 I am getting:

```
Cannot use Pimcore\Model\Object as Object because 'Object' is a special class name in ...
```

somebody had the same problem please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that Object is a reserved word in PHP 7.2

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
\Pimcore\Model\DataObject
```

instead of

```
\Pimcore\Model\Object
```